# what if my iphone app is rejected?

Tags: iphone

What if my application is rejected from app store? Do I need to take gap to retry or need to pay for that? How many trails I can make for app submission?

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Malleswar

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613430/how-do-i-contest-an-iphone-app-store-review

Answer (score 4):

Address Apple's concerns and resubmit.  There is no submission fee, limit, or waiting period.